# PHP Apache on ubuntu backward paths aren't working

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu

I've setup Apache on a new ubuntu system. The root folder for the domain is `/var/www/abc/web`

Inside the `abc` folder I've an image called `logo_out.jpg` and inside the web folder I've the same image called `logo_in.jpg`

I've a simple html file in the `/web` folder called `index.html` which contains only one line

```
<img src="../logo_out.jpg" alt="image"/>
```

which isn't working at all. It is completely weird. I did some more testings and I've noticed that `../` is never going backwards here. To make sure this, I tried this.

```
<img src="../logo_in.jpg" alt="image"/>
```

This shouldn't work normally because the filename is incorrect, but it is working. Even if I give `<img src="../../logo_in.jpg" alt="image"/>` it is taking the same `logo_in.jpg` inside the `web` folder.

I don't understand why this is happening. Am I missing any modules in Apache or anything?

FYI, I've `PHP 5.6` with `apache 2.4.29`

Comment: If the file `log_out.jpg` is outside of the document root, then you won't be able to use it in your HTML directly. You can only link to paths that are _inside_ the document root. Also, if the image is located directly in the document root, you could use `src="/theImage.jpg"` (the initial slash will make the path relative from the root).

Comment: `abc` is the root here

Comment: Then you should update your question since it says: _"The root folder for the domain is /var/www/abc/web"_, which would make `web` the document root, not `abc`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I missed it. I verified the root, it is  web. That's the issue. Thanks for pointing out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your server will (thankfully) block requests to paths **abov**e your web directory. You cannot request any files **above** your root web directory, that is not even possible by the RFC HTTP standard. No matter how **abov**e WEB DIR you will go with a HTML link, Chrome and other browsers will request the WEB DIR's root. If you make a link to

http://example.tld/../file.ext

browsers will request for

http://example.tld/file.ext

because it is impossible to request files **above** web root directory.

Comment: I really thought it was a fools post. And yeah, I am not a native english speaker so I mixed the words to specify the directory location. My bad, will fix it.